# java BufferedReader to BufferedWriter makes empty files

Tags: java, character-encoding

I am trying to convert ansii(latin-5) text file to utf-8 text file in a directory. I made a small mechanish to understand if the file is ansii or utf-8 however when i try to change ansii file to utf-8 program deletes all values in the text. Where am i doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Here is my code:

```
package altyazi;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class operation{
    public static int howmany =0;
    public static int howmanysmalli=0;
    public static double ratio;
    File myFile;
    public static void koddegıstır(String myfile) throws IOException{
        File file = new File(myfile);
        byte[] bytesArray = new byte[(int) file.length()];
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        fis.read(bytesArray);
        fis.close();
        int[] freqs = new int[256];
          for(byte b: bytesArray){
              freqs[b&0x0ff]++;
          }
          howmany = freqs[107]+freqs[75];
          howmanysmalli=freqs[253];
          System.out.println("Character \"k\" appears " + howmany +" times in the text "+myfile);
          ratio = (double)howmany/(double)bytesArray.length;
          System.out.println("How many: "+howmany);
          System.out.println("Length: "+bytesArray.length);
          System.out.println("Ratio: "+ratio);
          //Cp1254
          if(ratio<0.01){
              System.out.println("Text file is probably not turkish");
          }else{
              System.out.println("Text file is probably turkish");
              if(howmanysmalli>20){
                  String line;
                  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                            new FileInputStream(myfile),
                            "ISO-8859-9"));
                  Writer out = new BufferedWriter(
                            new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(
                                    myfile), "UTF-8"));
                  try {     
                        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                            out.write(line);
                            out.write("\n");

                        }

                    } finally {

                        br.close();
                        out.close();

                    }
              }else{
                  System.out.println("Passed as utf-8");
              }
          }
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems you are not flushing the bufferedwriter.
out.flush();

Comment: @SouravGulati He is *closing* it, which implies a flush.

Comment: `new FileOutputStream(myfile)` you are trashing over your input file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are overwriting the file when you create the `FileOutputStream`. This creates an empty file. You need to write to a *new* file, and delete the old one and rename the new one when complete.